# While attempting to import pygame, I got an error

Tags: python, pygame

While attempting to import pygame, I got the following error:

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I know this is not a 32b vs 64b problem, because I have attempted to follow fixes for that and none of them came up with anything.

Comment: Did you install pygame? If you have multiple Python versions, did you install pygame on the right one?

Comment: Also make sure you haven't saved a file called "pygame.py", otherwise you'll be importing that instead of the pygame library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a result of a few different things:

1) You didn't actually install pygame, or you installed the wrong version of pygame. This can be easily fixed by installing the correct version of pygame.

2) You installed pygame, but you didn't install it in the default directory. As a result, python doesn't know where to look for the install. You can point python to the correct install by:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("<the install path here>")
import pygame
```

This sets another directory for python to look for modules.